# How do I make jinja2 append rows to html table instead of overriding the old ones?

Tags: python, jinja2

My corrent code is the following:

```
<table id="items"> 
<tr>
  <th>Description</th>
  <th>Price</th>
</tr>
    {% for d in data %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ d.itemDes }}</td>
            <td>{{ d.itemPrice }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

But this doesnt keep the old rows

Comment: which rows are not kept in this example? what exactly is the output and what do you want it to be?

Comment: You should give minimal reproducible example as referred here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @kg_sYy the "data" is changing from time to time. So I want the loop to append rows to the table and keep the rows the previous loop created

Comment: Jinja just deals what is in "data" at the time of rendering the template. You want another type of solution for appending to existing page. Or if you re-render, then keep the old values in "data" yourself.